# How to record ip connections on my machine?

Tags: ip, network-monitoring

I have an ubuntu laptop and I would like to record my internet connection continuously.

In other words I want to save in a txt file all the ips that my machine connects to in a certain amount of time.

How can I get this?

EDIT:

The command `sudo tcpdump --immediate -e` returns an output that is too verbose.

Ideally I need only the list of unique destinations that my machine connects to in a certain amount of time. How can I get that?

Comment: Verbose output is to be expected. Try the 'etherape' or 'wireshark' packages for a few minutes of real-time monitoring, and you will see that web browsers and other network-connected applications may connect to an *enormous* number of IPs within a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

"Record continuously" and "record the IPs" aren't the same. However, if you install the `tcpdump` package, and read `man tcpdump`, you should be able to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant details of how to use `tcpdump` to achieve the stated goal?

Comment: You have not had time to read `man tcpdump`.

Comment: I'm not the asker. Your answer is basically RTFM, which isn't a quality answer.

Comment: `sudo tcpdump  --immediate -e`

Comment: Thanks this was helpful but it did not solve my problem. I have edited the question.